# Read .properties file in .xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have appcontext.xml file in the class path. I am using config.properties file in appcontext.xml to read database properties. Property file is stored in src/main/config/core/config.properties structure and I am using it in xml file as,

```
<property name="locations">
   <list>
        <value>${PF_CORE_HOME}/config/core/config.properties</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

but it gives error,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/prov-eng-2/prov-eng/provfwk/pf-core/src/main/config/core/config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.gsl.pf.core.AdaptorManager.<init>(AdaptorManager.java:28) ~[pf-core-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.gsl.pf.core.AdaptorManager.getInstance(AdaptorManager.java:34) ~[pf-core-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.gsl.pf.fwk.FrameworkLoader.initialize(FrameworkLoader.java:35) ~[pf-fwk-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.gsl.pf.scimsvr.app.Loader.initialize(Loader.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.gsl.pf.scimsvr.app.ScimServer.start(ScimServer.java:62) [classes/:na]
    at com.gsl.pf.scimsvr.app.ScimServer.main(ScimServer.java:47) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/prov-eng-2/prov-eng/provfwk/pf-core/src/main/config/core/config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:80) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

is there any other way to read .property file in .xml.

Comment: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/prov-eng-2/prov-eng/provfwk/pf-core/src/main/config/core/config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Did you read the exception?

Comment: `<value>classpath:/core/config.properties</value>` if file copied to class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way works if you do it properly.

Here's your issue:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/prov-eng-2/prov-eng/provfwk/pf-core/src/main/config/core/config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

You're reading this file from the CLASSPATH, but that path is not part of it.

You don't include /src in your CLASSPATH.  I'd put that .properties file in a /resources directory and package that into your CLASSPATH (e.g. a relative path under /classes).